# Setting up Oauth with Github for React Native

Tags: github, react-native, oauth, fetch

I'm using a react-native app. When registering for github oauth, what is the expected input for homepage url during registration?

I'm trying to utilize the web application flow for setting up oauth and I'm having trouble making a proper fetch for user auth.